# How can I change the location of toast notifications in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: toast notification in vs code]

The default position for notifications in VS code can be seen in the right-down corner; however, I need to use the top-right corner.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, this is not currently possible. In particular, see the following issue tickets:

- [Notifications: allow to control location of notification toasts #80604](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80604)
  Closed for not geting enough support from the community reaction votes.
- [Explore alternate locations for the notifications center
  #144330](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/144330)
  Not primarily about the location of the toast notifications, but the feature-request includes a suggestion to move toast notifications to the top-right to be consistent with other proposed changes.
- [Allow to change positions of notifications
  #53600](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/53600)
  Still open. <sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup> Some peoples' use-cases include that when they dock their terminal panel to the right of the workbench, their terminal prompt gets obscured by toast notifications. (I wonder if that's your use-case too?)

I'll update this post if it eventually gets implemented.

For your learning purposes / reference, I found the above by googling "`github vscode issues change position of toast notifications`".

Note: The UI originally wasn't like this- perhaps it was even worse. See [Add an option to display popup "toast" at the bottom of the screen #41975](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41975), which got closed as completed by [Implement new notifications UX #43770](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/43770).